# Guardar cambios en la base de datos al editar celda de DBGrid

Tags: delphi

Tengo una grilla con el detalle de un pedido y quiero, al editar la cantidad o el dinero a cuenta (cada uno en una columna distinta), aplicar los cambios en la base de datos.

Tengo un TClientDataSet "cdsdetpedido" con el detalle de pedido:

```
 procedure TDataModule1.cdsdetpedidoAcuentaChange(Sender: TField);
  begin
    DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.Edit;
    DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.Post;
    DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.ApplyUpdates(0);
  end;
```

También probé al salir de una celda:

```
procedure TPEDIDO.gpedidotempColExit(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  DataModule1.cdsdetpedido.Edit;
  if (gpedidotemp.Fields[gpedidotemp.SelectedIndex]=
  gpedidotemp.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('Acuenta')) then

  begin
   DataModule1.quact.Close;
   DataModule1.quact.ParamByName('acta').AsFloat := gpedidotemp.SelectedField.AsFloat ;
   DataModule1.quact.ParamByName('idp').AsInteger:= 
   gpedidotemp.DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('idproducto').AsInteger;

   DataModule1.quact.ExecSQL();

  end;
 end;
```

Pero no logro que se apliquen los cambios. en el ultimo código ejecuto un query pero tampoco lo logro, los valores llegan perfectamente.

Comment: Creo que no te has tomado el tiempo de investigar y entender como funcionan los estados de los _DataSets_ en Delphi y los datasets en general. Lo cierto es que el evento `OnChange` de un campo de un _DataSet_ se va a disparar solo si el DataSet está en edición/inserción.  Lo menciono porque con este modelo de controles asociados a datos, no resulta natural llevar los cambios de manera inmediata (cada vez que se _toca_ un campo) a la base de datos. Lo más pronto que el modelo te lo permitiría sería llevarlos a la base de datos cuando se termina de editar un registro completo.

Comment: De hecho, hay controles del tipo `TDBNavigator` que le dan control al usuario sobre la edición de registros. Con estos puede descartar los cambios hechos a un registro en inserción/edición, invocando al método `cancel`.  Por otro lado, utilizas ClientDataSets en un entorno cliente/servidor, que te permiten acumular cambios en varios registros... si no te interesa esa funcionalidad, considera dejar de lado los ClientDataSets y utilizar directamente los componentes de la capa de conexión a datos. (a menos que tengas otra buena razón para usarlos).

Comment: Menciono esto último porque, si quitas del medio el ClientDataSet, los cambios irían de manera automática a la base de datos cada vez que el usuario cambie de registro en la grilla.

Comment: Es decir me recomendas agregar un componente TDBNavigator.. Tanto para agregar registros nuevos o editar/eliminar de la grilla de detalle

Comment: El problema es que el dataset de la grilla de detalle se llena con un TSQLQuery, por lo que un Navigator no tendra efecto. Otra alternativa seria tener un query para cada operacion(insercion,edicion,etc)

Comment: No es necesario el uso de TDBNavigator, pero ver su funcionamiento y jugar con él te puede ayudar a entender cuales son y cómo operan los cambios de estado de un DataSet en Delphi. Sobre tu último comentario, ¿la grilla está conectada a un ClientDataSet o a un SQLQuery?

Comment: Esta conectada a un Tclientdatset pero este tiene un provider con un SQLQuery.

Comment: Finalmente encontre el error y era que no tenia un campo id autoincremental y unico en la tabla detallepedido. Ahora el DBNavigator funciona perfecto aunque mi codigo tambien.